# How to check if a number with 15 digits contains asterisk characters in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String which have 15 digit . From the seventh digit to the twelfth digit is hidden by the star character (*). Example : "121233******450".

I want to create a boolean function which return true if the string has 15 digit and the seventh digit to the twelfth digit is hidden by the star character (*)

Example :

```
boolean checkNumber(String nbrToCheck) {
 // check if the number has 15 digits and contains six asterisk
 // I think to use this : "^.*(?:\\*.*){6}$"
   String regex = ".*\\*.*\\*.*";
  return boolean valid = nbrToCheck.matches(regex);
}
```

How can i do it easily in java with regex or not

Comment: There is no possible way an `int` can contain `*` characters (other than perhaps one as an ascii code). An `int` is not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a boolean function which return true if the string has 15 digit and the seventh digit to the twelfth digit is hidden by the star character (*)

I think you meant has 15 characters.  You can match the supplied string of 6 digits, 6 asterisks and 3 digits using the method below.

- `\\d{n}`  matches `n` digits
- `\\*{n}`  matches `n` asterisks (escaped since * has
   special regexp meaning)

```
System.out.println(checkNumber("123456******123"));

static boolean  checkNumber(String nbrToCheck) {
     return nbrToCheck.matches("\\d{6}\\*{6}\\d{3}");
}
```

prints

```
true
```

Comment: The asterisk must be quoted to remove its special meaning.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: it is escaped with the `\\*`. `\*` would be the regex-escaping, and the second `\ ` escapes the _other_ `\ ` (necessary for being in a java `String`).

Comment: @BeUndead. Yes. I was explaining why the asterisk was quoted, not pointing out a bug.  Regexps are quite terse.